# SQL - Join column with condition if it is <> Blank

Tags: sql-server, join, query

I want to join two tables together using `ColumnA` and `ColumnB`.  However, `ColumnB` is sometimes a blank string.

If `ColumnB` is blank, I just want to to join using `ColumnA`. But if `ColumnB` is not blank, I want to use both `ColumnA` and `ColumnB`.

My current query:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM 
  Table1 A
LEFT JOIN 
  Table2 B
    ON UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(A.ColumnA))) =UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(B.ColumnA))) 
        AND UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(A.ColumnB))) =UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(B.ColumnB)))
```

Comment: What should happen if `Table1.ColumnB` isn't blank but `Table2.ColumnB` is blank?

Comment: @J.D. usually such thing won't happen. But I'm thinking if it happens then apply condition to join on Table1.ColumnA = Table2.ColumnA

Answer (score 1):

For clarity, I'm going to exclude the `UPPER/LTRIM/RTRIM` bits.  These are red flags (see below), but outside the scope of the answer.

This will get you the result you need:

```
SELECT
  /* Columns */
FROM
  Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN
  Table2 T2
    ON T2.ColumnA = T1.ColumnA
        AND 
          (
            T2.ColumnB = T1.ColumnB
              OR T2.ColumnB = ''
              OR T1.ColumnB = ''
          )
```

In other words, `T2.ColumnA = T1.ColumnA` must always evaluate to `TRUE`, but only one of the following (mutually exclusive) conditions must hold.

---

For your sake, I hope this is just part of ETL code used on uncleansed staging data.  It would be *especially troubling* to see things like  `UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(A.ColumnA)))` used for join conditions in a database, as this would indicate two large problems:

1. The requisite PK-FK relationship for the join does not exist
2. There are no data quality rules applied to the columns in question

In fact, you should never have to use this type of logic (at least outside of ETL/staging work) as key values cannot be `NULL` by definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a case statement in your join.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 A LEFT JOIN Table2 B
        ON CASE 
           WHEN datalength(ColumnB)=0 AND A.ColumnA = B.ColumnA THEN 1
           WHEN datalength(ColumnB)<>0 AND A.ColumnA = B.ColumnA  AND
                                       A.ColumnB = B.ColumnB THEN 1
           ELSE 0
           END = 1
```